# Tokens not being replaced in node bodies

Tags: 7, tokens, 10

I have a default install of Drupal 7 with the Tokens module. I'm using `[current-page:title]` in a node body, but the content isn't being replaced.

I've looked for settings and at the Token module page, and nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: The Tokens module doesn't replace tokens on node bodies. Do you have a module that is supposed to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @kiamlaluno mentioned in the comment, neither the token API in core nor the token.module replaces tokens in node bodies.

For that, you need a module like [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter).

Comment: And you have to select the checkbox Replace Tokens in `admin/config/content/formats` after the module is installed.